# Android reflection: Bluetooth visibility time to unlimited

Tags: android, reflection, bluetooth, visibility

There are a lot of post about the bluetooth visibility.
The visibility is limited to a certain time with a maximum of 300 seconds.

When the 300 seconds are over, the visibility status will change.
When it's changed I call the method again, but then user still has to confirm it, every single time.

I've read some articles about reflection.
Could I make it possible, even if it's a lot of work, to call an android class / method to set it to an unlimited time? Or confirm the dialog automatically?

I'm very curious if it's possible to make it, using reflection.

Greetz

Comment: Yes it is possible, you'll need root access to the phone and need to research the BlueZ implementation.

Comment: How about using reflection without root access? Is that an option? I wanna make an app that's available for a lot of users in the Android market. Because the group of android users with root access is limited under my target group of people

Comment: There is no java API for phones to do this, not even in the hidden API. For tables, yes you can set indefinite. This feature is expected in Ice Cream Sandwich.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to confirm the dialog automatically if you have access to source code: 
open the file packages/apps/Settings/res/values/bools.xml

change the line :

```
<bool name="auto_confirm_bluetooth_activation_dialog">false</bool>
```

to

```
<bool name="auto_confirm_bluetooth_activation_dialog">true</bool>
```

of course you need to rebuild and flash.